# Is it a bug that zsh print the full string with printf '%.s'?

Tags: shell, zsh, printf

The command `` printf '%.0s-' `seq 1 30`; echo `` works fine in all shells tested:

```
/bin/jsh        : ------------------------------
/bin/attsh      : ------------------------------
/bin/y2sh       : ------------------------------
/bin/ash        : ------------------------------
/bin/dash       : ------------------------------
/bin/b203sh     : ------------------------------
/bin/b43sh      : ------------------------------
/bin/b44sh      : ------------------------------
/bin/bash       : ------------------------------
/bin/ksh        : ------------------------------
/bin/ksh93      : ------------------------------
/bin/lksh       : ------------------------------
/bin/mksh       : ------------------------------
/bin/zsh        : ------------------------------
/bin/zsh4       : ------------------------------
```

Except for jsh (heirloom shell), y2sh [Yet another shell, version 2.39](https://github.com/magicant/yash) and lksh (Legacy Korn shell) all other implement a printf builtin:

```
/bin/attsh      : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/ash        : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/dash       : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/b203sh     : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/b43sh      : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/b44sh      : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/bash       : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/ksh        : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/ksh93      : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/mksh       : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/zsh        : printf is a shell builtin
/bin/zsh4       : printf is a shell builtin
```

But this line: `` printf '%.s-' `seq 1 30`; echo `` makes (only) zsh fail:

```
/bin/attsh      : ------------------------------
/bin/ash        : ------------------------------
/bin/dash       : ------------------------------
/bin/b203sh     : ------------------------------
/bin/b43sh      : ------------------------------
/bin/b44sh      : ------------------------------
/bin/bash       : ------------------------------
/bin/ksh        : ------------------------------
/bin/ksh93      : ------------------------------
/bin/mksh       : ------------------------------
/bin/zsh        : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30-
/bin/zsh4       : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30-
```

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05) states that:

> The precision shall take the form of a  ( '.' ) followed by a decimal digit string; a null digit string is treated as zero.

Even if the `s` format specification states (in the same link):

> If the precision is omitted from the argument, it shall be taken to be infinite, so all bytes up to the end of the string shall be written.

It could be reasonable argued that a "missing" precision digit is not "omitted" but has been set to a "null" and therefore should be interpreted as zero.

It would follow that zsh has a bug here.

Is that the correct explanation?

Comment: I'd say "bug". "Precision" refers to both the `.` and the optional digit string; an omitted precision looks like to `%s`, not `%.s`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is a bug (38306). The fix was released in Zsh 5.3.

Source: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/e1c745a0dca56afb9cfcace1ef59449152290188

Comment: Great sleuthing; it's worth noting that the fix isn't in the officially released v5.2, however, so as of this writing the latest official release doesn't have the fix yet.